# XCode 12 Preview Crashes when adding Firebase SDK Swift UI 2.0

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui

Since the last Xcode update to 12.0.1 SwiftUI previews crashes when is added to the project.

The crash log hints that the problem is located in the firebase sdk, more specific the
GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary

```
    System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread: 3 Dispatch queue: com.google.GDTCORFlatFileStorage

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:]: URL is nil'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Firebase (6.33) is integrated via cocoapods (1.10.0.rc.1) with
Xcode 12.0.1 on Catalina 10.15.7

There is an open issue on [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6574)
Someone found a solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading GoogleDataTransport from 7.4.0 to 7.3.0 fixes the problem
=> pod 'GoogleDataTransport', '7.3.0'

Answer (score 4):

Downgrading GoogleDataTransport from 7.4.0 to 7.3.0 does the trick however If you use Firebase 6.33.0 downgrading will not work because version GoogleDataTransport 7.4 version was locked in Firebase Core podspec. According to crash report Preview crashes in AppDelegate `FirebaseApp.configure()`, so if Firebase functionality isn't required in DEBUG it might be excluded with macros:

```
#if RELEASE
   FirebaseApp.configure()
#endif
```